# Python 3.3 on windows os.sep wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using a Active Python 3.3 Installation on windows. running a script

```
import os, sys
print("jointest",os.path.join('hallo','file.txt'),"\nSys:",sys.platform,"Sep:",os.sep)
```

jointest hallo\file.txt

Sys: win32 Sep: \

In the Python Interactive shell

> > > os.sep

returns the expected '\\'

What's wrong?

Comment: So i tried `import os` and ` print(os.sep)`. I see there's a difference between the shell and sending it from a print. Can you elaborate what your problem is? But i think the print command just removes one \ on purpose. Maybe try another way to output data.

Comment: Well, debugging the correct join on windows becomes difficult. How coud I the print/debug the actual content of a string?

Comment: As far as i know, a print should work just fine, it's the double backlash what it's not the actual content of the string, but since that one only happens when you call it without print, that shouldn't be an issue. To explain this better: when you type in the shell, you are NOT printing, you are using repr. Hence that's why it shows up the double backlash.

Comment: The same way the `'\n'` represents a newline sequence in a string literal, the `'\\'` represents a single backslash in a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. The separator is just a single backslash. However, when you type `os.sep` in the Python shell, Python prints the `repr` value which has quotes and another backslash. Try:

```
print(os.sep)
```

from the Python shell.